# ckfinder removing wrapped a tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to implement a CMS using CK Editor 4 to edit certain editable fragments of a web page. But it is changing the markup, despite my best efforts to configure it so it does not.

One example of this is the following original markup loaded into the editor

```
<article class="last"> 
    <a href="#" class="promo-m">
        <div class="info"> 
                <h3>Access for All</h3>
                <p>We want everyone to enjoy the benefits of good, clear communication.</p>
                <p class="product-cta">
                    Find out more
                </p>
        </div>        
    </a>
</article>
```

After the editor renders this in wysiwyg mode, when saving (or viewing in source mode) it is changing the markup to this:

```
<article class="last">
<div class="info">
<h3><a class="promo-m" href="#">Access for All</a></h3>

<p><a class="promo-m" href="#">We want everyone to enjoy the benefits of good, clear communication.</a></p>

<p class="product-cta"><a class="promo-m" href="#">Find out more </a></p>
</div>
</article>
```

In other words, it is removing the wrapping a tag and applying an a tag to each of the containing elements. 
Unfortunately this is affecting the styles which apply to the contents, and meaning that to change any links would mean changing it for each of the containing linked elements.

I am turning off the ACF using this configuration:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
    allowedContent: true
});
```

can anyone help on this?

The code is up on jsfiddle.net (based on an earlier stackoverflow answer)
http://jsfiddle.net/6FnRf/14/
You can click the source button in the editor, paste the article contents in, click to view in wysiwyg mode, then back to source to see the way it changes the markup.